# aspx Login page takes long time due to loading config values in session. How can I make it faster

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a configuration table in the database which is loaded into the session on the login page. The login is taking long time. This is a aspx page and makes a call to a stored procedure which has a simple select query. How can I make the login load faster?

Answer (score 0):

1. Test your SP how long its take.
2. Test your web page without the SP, maybe there is another problem that cause it.
3. Change your code. try to write different access to your SP